# Unity3d. Particles trigger для многих Сollider2d

Tags: unity3d

Пишу игру, в которой одновременно на экране присутствуют много юнитов (у каждого есть свой `collider2d`). Игра 2D, с видом сверху вниз.

Пытаюсь реализовать залп лучников, в котором летит одновременно 100 стрел.

---

Тут нужно оговориться, что стрелы фактически перемещаются в той же плоскости что и юниты, но на вид должно казаться что они летят высоко над землей, а в конце пути падают на землю

---

Если обрабатывать каждую стрелу отдельным игровым объектом, то, с учетом множества юнитов уже присутствующих на сцене, игра просто упадет от недостатка производительности. Поэтому было решено использовать систему частиц.

В конце своего пути стрелы должны наносить урон юнитам, если попали по ним. Вот тут и начались проблемы, так как модуль системы частиц **Collision** не подходит. Если пытаться использовать его, то стрелы врезаются в юнитов на любом отрезке своего пути (так как игра 2d), а должны это делать только в конце пути (например, когда остановятся). Модуль **Triggers**, так же не подходит, так как он позволяет задать только 5 коллайдеров для проверки, а юнитов у меня может быть больше сотни.

Как можно реализовать нужное поведение системы частиц? Или, возможно, вообще не стоит использовать частицы?

Comment: А частицы партикл по-твоему не отдельные обьекты? Ну если залп стрел у тебя связывает визуальную часть с логикой(каждая стрела наносит урон), то только поиск попадания каждой стрелы в ручную, и партикли тут не помогут. Другое дело, если ты создашь пару абстрактных обьектов и за каждым будет стоять небольшая группа стрел, то можно чекать не большую область вокруг этих обьектов на попадание

Comment: Ну так, то партиклы не являются GameObject. Они обрабатываются самой системой частиц, а не отдельными скримтами унаследованными от Monobihaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если долго мучиться, что нибудь получится...

И так, пришло решение **не** очень оптимизированное, но рабочее.

Вот так выглядит кривая зависимости ограничения скорости частиц от времени их жизни:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал скрипт для объекта с системой частиц. Сначала пробовал в методе `Update` вытаскивать с системы частиц все частицы и проверять их на нужное состояние (когда время жизни будет максимально приближено к моменту "столкновения стрел с землей", на рисунке выше это 0.4 от общего времени жизни частицы).
Если условие выполнялось, происходил `Physics2D.CircleCast` в месте положения данной частицы. Но так как частицы представлены структурами, то пришлось их вытаскивать каждый кадр. Это сильно грузило систему.

Очень странно, на мой взгляд, но проблему помогло решить создание коллайдера на объекте системы частиц, ссылка на который и была передана в модyль системы частиц **Triggers**. Сам коллайдер расположен так, чтоб все частицы в конце своего пути оказались внутри него.

Вот так выглядит система частиц в редакторе unity, во время симуляции:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит настройка модуля **Triggers**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все вычисления с метода `Update` перенеслись в метод `OnParticleTrigger`. Частицы вытаскивались с системы частиц с помощью метода `GetTriggerParticles`, а сами вычисления проходили при нахождении частиц внутри коллайдера (т.е `ParticleSystemTriggerEventType.Inside`). Теперь, по крайней мере, пока стрелы летят далеко от места своего падения, расчеты не происходят...

Код класса для объекта с системой частиц:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(ParticleSystem))]
public class ArrowsValley : MonoBehaviour
{
    //система частиц
    ParticleSystem particleSystem;
    //список для получения частиц из коллайдера
    List<ParticleSystem.Particle> trigPartc;
    //слои на которые будем делать каст
    int layerMask;
    //юнит, которого мы получим (или нет) из каста
    Unit unit;
    //ну и сам результат аста
    RaycastHit2D rhit;

    //урон, который нанесем юниту, в которого попадет стрела
    [SerializeField] Weapon.Damage damage;

    void Start()
    {
        //получаем систему частиц
        particleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        //создаем пустой список, предполагая что в него влезут все частицы
        trigPartc = new List<ParticleSystem.Particle>(particleSystem.main.maxParticles);

        //вычисляем нужный слой для каста
        layerMask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer(Squad.UnitFraction.ALLY.ToString());
        layerMask = layerMask | 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer(Squad.UnitFraction.NEUTRAL.ToString());
        layerMask = layerMask | 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer(Squad.UnitFraction.ENEMY.ToString());

    }

    private void OnParticleTrigger()
    {
        // получаем частицы, которые находятся внутри коллайдера модуля Triggers
        int count = particleSystem.GetTriggerParticles(ParticleSystemTriggerEventType.Inside, trigPartc);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            //убеждаемся, что стрела остановилась
            if (trigPartc[i].velocity.x == 0)
            {
                //убеждаемся, что стрела существует уже столько чтоб только что "коснутся земли"
                float t = trigPartc[i].remainingLifetime - trigPartc[i].startLifetime * (1 - 0.4f);
                t = t < 0 ? -t : t;
                if (t <= 0.03f)
                {
                    //убедившись что стрела находится в моменте "столкновения с землей"
                    //производим каст круга
                    rhit = Physics2D.CircleCast(trigPartc[i].position, 0.5f, Vector2.zero, 0, layerMask);

                    if (rhit)
                    {
                        //если стрела попала в юнита, получаем его и наносим урон
                        unit = rhit.collider.GetComponent<Unit>();
                        unit.TakeDamageFromArrow(damage);

                        //после попадания стрелу можно удалить
                        //для этого выставляем ей отрицательное время жизни и система сама позаботится об удалении
                        ParticleSystem.Particle p = trigPartc[i];
                        p.remainingLifetime = -1;
                        trigPartc[i] = p;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     //тут внимание!
     //если мы делали какие то изменения в самих частицах (а мы делали)
     //то нужно закинуть измененные частицы обратно в систему частиц    
     particleSystem.SetTriggerParticles(ParticleSystemTriggerEventType.Inside, trigPartc);
    }
}
```

Вот такой вышел результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(На гифке стрелы рисуются под юнитами. Это легко исправить выставив нужный `sortingLayer` в модуле системы частиц **Renderer**, мне просто лень было, извините)

Если у кого то есть идея получше, пожалуйста, поделитесь ею в комментариях, а может и ответ напишите, с радостью отмечу его как правильный.

Comment: Приведи пример реализации

Comment: Ок. Вернусь с пар, отредактирую ответ.

Comment: ну, я старался)

Answer (score 1):

Весь overhead в Physics2D.CircleCast как понял, ну и сам партикл чутка добавляет. Так как объектов динамических много, происходит куча проверок лишних. Можно ограничить кол-во проверок. Вот у тебя есть триггер зона в которую летят стрелы. На триггер зоне можно сделать поиск объектов, которые в нее входят и создать список. И вот стрелы проверять по этому списку. Тут можно несколько способов проверки пересечения стрел с юнитами реализовать.

1). Если у юнитов коллайдеры квадратные/прямоугольные, то искать пересечение коробок, можно зафиксировать частный вариант размера для стрелы, если у юнитов все одинаковые коллайдеры, также можно зафиксировать. И отсчитывать только от центра объектов + зафиксированные размеры. Иначе можно доставать bounds из коллайдеров юнитов и мучаться через них.

2). Наверно самый эффективный, если зоны пересечения(коллайдеры) стрелы и юнита принять как круг. То можно просто расстояние проверять, для попадания, надо чтобы расстояние от стрелы до юнита было меньше суммы их радиусов( а еще лучше через квадраты расстояний, тогда корни считать не надо будет dist^2<=(r1+r2)^2). Радиусы придется где-то реализовывать, если для стрелы можно зафиксировать, то у юнитов... можно напрямую запрашивать(закешировать не помешает на момент проверки), можно сделать несколько списков под каждый радиус(также отсеить заранее, можно прям при вхождении в триггер)

**Советы:**

1).У триггера для поиска юнитов жестко зафиксировать слои с которыми он может взаимодействовать, чтобы не проверять объекты, которые не нужны. Ну или совсем свой поиск попадания юнитов в данную зону сделать.

2).Можно расстояния считать руками, без использования всяких Vector.Distance или sqrMagnitude(тупо (v.x-v2.x)*(v.x-v2.x)+(v.y-v2.y)*(v.y-v2.y) ). Избежишь сильного overhead на вызов этих функций в цикле(на 100 стрел и 100 юнитов, будет в самом худшем случае 10000 проверок).

3).С триггерами беда, если объект выключиться, то он не получит команду Exit, поэтому при проверке по списку игнорить выключенные объекты) Либо делать костыли, обходящие эту проблему(при выключении насильно сообщать триггеру, что обьект удаляется из списка).

4).Перед тем как проверять на попадание, можно закешировать позиции юнитов и стрел, чтобы при каждой проверке не вызывать position.

5).Использовать возможности распараллеливания вычислений.

6).Если объектов становиться реально огромное кол-во. То можно область триггера подразбивать на меньшие области(причем динамически в зависимости от плотности юнитов на квадратный метр). И так как стрелы летят прямо, то можно высчитать подобласть куда приземлится стрела, и проверять попадание стрелы только со списком юнитов внутри области. Но это решение вносит много нюансов, которые надо будет учесть, ограничений с которыми придется смириться и т.д.

7).Можно совсем "схардкорить", избегать партикла. Сделать массив матриц трансформа стрел, смещать вручную. А рисовать напрямую через какой-нибудь Gpu instancing или meshInstancing(чтобы избегать overhead на всякие Renderer и drawcalls). Но тут есть какие-то ограничения на платформы, надо смотреть и пробовать.

Короче дерзай) Все советы полезны ток для большого количества объектов.

Comment: Спасибо за советы) Пока что производительность позволяет пользоваться текущей реализацией, и есть много других задач, но при последующей оптимизации обязательно воспользуюсь ими.